# Hibernate many-to-many: Criteria for looking up all class A which DO NOT contain class B

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a many-to-many relationship between Item and ItemCategory. For an Item, I want to know what categories the Item is not in. I also want to know for an ItemCategory, which items the category does not have. The SQL for the second one should be something like this:

```
SELECT item 
FROM Item AS item 
WHERE item.id NOT IN (SELECT item2.id FROM Item AS item2 LEFT JOIN item2.categories AS cat WHERE cat.id = ?)
```

I'm using DetachedCriteria because I'm including this as part of an ad-hoc query. I think I'm close to a solution, but it seems like Hibernate is not generating the correct solution. My code has this:

```
DetachedCriteria subquery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Item.class, "item");
DetachedCriteria catSubquery = subquery.createCriteria("categories", "cat");
SimpleExpression criterion = Restrictions.eq("id", value);

catSubquery.add(criterion);
criteria.add(Subqueries.propertyNotIn("id", subquery));
```

The generated SQL looks like this:

```
select ... 
from wine.categories this_ 
where this_.CATEGORY_ID not in 
  (select this0__.CATEGORY_ID as y0_ 
   from wine.categories this0__ 
   where item1_.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID=?)
```

Note that it's missing the join table (called "item_categories"). How do I fix this?

More info: here's the Hibernate mapping of "ItemCategory.items"

```
<set name="items" table="item_categories" lazy="true" inverse="true"
  cascade="none" sort="unsorted">
  <cache usage="nonstrict-read-write"/>

  <key column="ITEM_CATEGORY_ID">
  </key>

  <many-to-many class="com.dr_dee_sw.wine.dto.Item" column="ITEM_ID"
    outer-join="auto"/>

</set>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turns out to be much more mundane. There was a bug in the version of Hibernate I was using (3.2). It in essence did not support what I needed. Just upgrading to Hibernate 3.6 did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
// get all items which are not in the specified category

List<Item> itemsNotInCategory = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Item.class)
    .add(Subquery.propertyNotIn("id", DetachedCriteria.forClass(Category.class)
        .add(Restrictions.eq("id", catid))
        .createAlias("items", "item")
        .setProjections(Projections.Distinct(Projections.Property("item.id")))
    ))
    .List();
```

Comment: That seemed to fix one error that I was having, but it still is not specifying the join table. The subquery is now "select distinct item1_.ITEM_ID as y0_ from categories this0__ where this0__.CATEGORY_ID=?"

Comment: looks like a mapping error. can you post the mapping of category? and where does it get `item1_` from?

Comment: item1_ came from me trying out different aliases in attempts to debug it.